# What is the status of traits theory in personality psychology?

Tags: personality

Currently, what is the status of traits theory in personality psychology? Is it still a satisfactory theoretical framework to which to refer? What about its personality tests? Could you support your answer with recent scientific literature, please?

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite vague. The trait perspective is probably the most actively researched perspective in personality research. Many thousands of papers are published each year using trait-based measures. And there is a lot of active debate about theoretical and measurement issues.

Comment: I know this. I need a recent paper which attests that it is a good approach for the study of personality, but under the keywords: "status" "trait psychology" "2015" or "2014", etc., I could not find one. Come up only applied research articles and critics on the theoretical approach.